# AWS API Gateway Integration Request setup automation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to use the AWS API Gateway+Swagger to route the request to my express backend. I can't figure out how to automate the setup of the integration request as the Swagger file has no details on it.

I'm also having difficulty with the **endpoint url** parameter when setting my method requests to GET/VPC Link on the integration type

For example:

My api gateway path is /info/car/{model}/aggregate

Now the endpoint url is http://carapi.com/info/car/{model}/aggregate

I have lots of gateway paths all of which are the same paths that my carapi.com site uses, so I don't want to keep retyping the path over and over. When entering in the endpoint url, I was able to simplify not having to type carapi.com by using stage variables turning my endpoint url to

http://${stageVariables.carApi}/info/car/{model}/aggregate

However after reading https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#stagevariables-template-reference

I see that there is also a $context available, but it gives me an error(when I try to call the api in postman, says 'internal server error' for the message) when I try to implement the context (which through that link shows that I can implement the path).

http://${stageVariables.carApi}/${context.resourcePath}

So my question is: how do I automate the setup of Integration requests so I don't have to manually setup each and every one(as I have hundreds of paths)? Is there also anyway to not have to set the paths manually for the endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any solution which is ready to use.

In my project, we wrote a custom solution that downloads the application Swagger json, parses it, adds the required integration and generates another json file. Then we import that into API Gateway. This has been converted as a Jenkins job and runs as a post job of microservice deployment.

Another way is, instead of generating the json, directly call API Gateway APIs and add the integration.